# pytest is not running any tests

Tags: python, pytest

My tests are in the following folder structure. Though I have also placed a sample test in the root, which doesn't work either. I get `no tests ran in 6.08s`

```
root/
    test/
        integrations/
                    test_sample.py
                    __init__.py
    __init__.py
```

I have tried using the command `pytest` by itself as well as specifying the test location `pytest ./test/integrations/test_sample.py`

I've been using a class to define multiple tests, but simple functions aren't running either.

Class:

```py
class TestClass:
    def add(self):
        pass
```

Function:

```py
def add():
    pass
```

Comment: You can [verify which tests were discovered and collected](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/pythoncollection.html#finding-out-what-is-collected) using command `pytest --collect-only` (in the output watch for "collected N items" and the following collection list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a *test* as function with a name beginning with `test`. See pytest's docs: [test-discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).

In this *test* or function:

1. instantiate your class
2. and run the class' method or function

```py
import pytest

# this class will be tested 
class ClassUnderTest:
    def add(self):
        return "it ran"

# This test will run because its name begins with "test"
def test_add():
    cls = ClassUnderTest()
    assert cls.add() == "it ran"

# This won't run because its name does not begin with "test"
def run_add():
    cls = ClassUnderTest()
    assert cls.add() == "it ran"

# ===== 1 passed in 0.05s =====
```

Comment: I was missing test_ in front of my method names, and the additional detail you provided here is great. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Methods name should start with **test_**. (inside class or out) is this what you're missing?

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm missing. I'm accepting the other more detailed answer however.

Comment: Not exactly ... pytest's [test-discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) looks for functions beginning with prefix `test` (the following underscore is though recommended as good naming-convention).

Comment: Your answer would usually fit as comment, maybe you can elaborate and illustrate by code-example how to achieve running [tests grouped in a `TestClass`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class) ️

Comment: Because I could not add comment, stack-overflow gave an error I have to have 50 reputation to add comment, but any way thanks for your feedback